# Using Paperclip for nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form, nested-forms

I'm trying to use paperclip to attach `Files` to a `Log` using a nested form with simple form. I was able to attach a single file when the file was an attribute to the model but I need to be able to associate multiple files to a log (one to many) which is why I now have 2 models. I'm getting the following error but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

> No handler found for
>   [#,
>   @original_filename="1314e40ac73ab769790aea881730e12f.jpg",
>   @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"log[documents_attributes][0][attachment][]\";
>   filename=\"1314e40ac73ab769790aea881730e12f.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type:
>   image/jpeg\r\n">,
>
> ## ,
>
> @original_filename="fsdfsdafsad-large.png", @content_type="image/png",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"log[documents_attributes][0][attachment][]\";
>   filename=\"fsdfsdafsad-large.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">]

`Document` model:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }

  belongs_to :log

  has_attached_file :attachment
  validates :log, presence: true
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

`Log` model:

```
class Log < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :server
  has_many :documents, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :documents
end
```

`Log` controller:

```
  # GET /logs/new
  def new
    @log = Log.new
    @log.documents.build
  end

  # POST /logs
  # POST /logs.json
  def create
    @log = Log.new(log_params)

    if params[:documents_attributes]
      params[:documents_attributes].each do |doc|
        @log.documents.create(attachment: doc)
      end
    end

    #binding.pry
    respond_to do |format|
      if @log.save
        binding.pry
        format.html { redirect_to log_path(@log), notice: 'Log was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @log }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @log.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def log_params
  params.require(:log).permit(:user_id, documents_attributes: [:log_id, attachment: []])
end
```

`Log` form view

```
<%= simple_form_for @log, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', enctype: 'multipart/form-data', local: true, multipart: true }   do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :documents, @log.documents do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input :attachment, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Update:** The error is triggered from `@log = Log.new(log_params)` in the `create` action of my `Log` controller.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip is designed to accept one file per 'column'. You cannot add multiple files in the attachment of `Document`. The solution is to either find another gem that support multiple files (carrierwave would be the most popular), or make a new resource (for example `Attachment`) that belongs_to `Document` and add the `has_attached_file` there.

PS: The error you get is happening because in your `log_params` you are permiting attachment expecting it to return multiple values and paperclip cannot handle attachment that way.